# Is there any error for adding a new data to realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

```
private lateinit var cDatabaseRef: DatabaseReference

private fun addUserToDatabase (uid:String,custID:String,custName:String,custPostAddress:String,custPhoneNumber:String,email:String){
       try{
            cDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            val newCustomer = Customer(custName,email,custID,custPostAddress,custPhoneNumber,uid)
            cDatabaseRef.child("Customers").child(uid).setValue(newCustomer).addOnSuccessListener { Toast.makeText(this, "Success added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                val intent = Intent(this, CustLoginActivity::class.java)
                finish()
                startActivity(intent)
            }

        } catch(e : Exception){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Some error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    }
```

The problem is, the Success added does not appear and the Realtime Database of firebase does not add any data. I also addOnFailureListener and OnCanceledListener, but both do not detect the error.
Although there is no error, the database does not add any new data

Comment: Add an `OnFailureListener` as well and check what error do you get there

Comment: Yes, it can’t throw on failure because it’s an asynchronous function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the URL of the real time database does not contain in the jason file which may cause by I include the jason file before I create a real-time database. The solution is below

```
 cDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("AddingURL from firebase realtime database").getReference()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a try-catch when writing data to the Realtime Database. [DatabaseReference#setValue(Object value)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#setValue(java.lang.Object)) returns an object of type [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html). That being said, you can use [addOnCompleteListener()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#addOnCompleteListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener%3CTResult%3E)), to check if the task is successful or if it failed with an Exception. In code, should look like this:

```
cDatabaseRef.child("Customers").child(uid).setValue(newCustomer).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Data written successfully.")
    } else {
        task.exception?.message?.let {
            Log.d(TAG, it)   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: actually the problem is the Realtime database does not adding any thing

Comment: Have you even tried the solution above? Is the else part triggered?

Comment: non for it. The email and password successful added into the authentication, but the realtime database does not get any data

Comment: Ok, but I have asked you if you tried the solution in my answer. Is the else part triggered?

Comment: both do not trigger

Comment: Then most likely you don't have an internet connection, right? As must be one, or the other.